# Catching ifstream exception in main

Tags: c++, exception, fstream

Im trying to catch an exception thrown when an error ocurred reading a file in a class method from main. The simplified code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    A(const std::string filename)
    {
       std::ifstream file;
       file.exceptions( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
       file.open(filename);
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::string filename("file.txt");
    try
    {
        A MyClass(filename);
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error reading file" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

I compile this code with:

```
 $ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

If file.txt exists nothing happens, but when it doesn't, the program terminates with the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
    what(): basic_ios::clear
zsh: abort (core dumped) ./a.out
```

But I expected the code to catch the exception and show the error message. Why is it not catching the exception?

Comment: Which compiler version? Works fine here.

Comment: @Christian Hackl g++ vresion 5.3.0

Comment: @Msegade It's a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66145).

Answer (score 3):

You can get it to work in GCC by adding `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to the command line. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4ad0734122e8881) is a working example with GCC.

From the comments (especially LogicStuff's tests) below and my own test it seems that in clang and MSVC it does not produce this error.

Thanks to LogicStuff's comment above we now know that this is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66145). Because in GCC C++03 ios::failure doesn't derive from runtime_error and so was not caught.

Another option could be to change to:

```
try
{
    A MyClass(filename);
}
catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
{
    std::cerr << "Error reading file\n";
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "Some other error\n";
}
```

Comment: Does not crash [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c52d4b1cce7814b8). And `std::ifstream::failure` is supposed to be same as `std::ios_base::failure`. It's inherited.

Comment: `std::ios_base::failure` and `std::ifstream::failure` are the *same* type.

Comment: Since `exceptions` in `ifstream` is inherited from `std::basic_ios` It should be the same type

Comment: Check [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0518c8c69a83979) out, it crashes on GCC, but not with Clang (above).